# Windows 7 BSOD - ntoskrnl?

Tags: windows-7, crash

2 new HP Pavilion notebooks with 7 Home Premium pre-loaded with Norton.  My first act was to use the Norton Removal Tool and load ZoneAlarm free and AVG Free.  Frequent random BSOD's ever since...I found my way into Debug and have had various reports regarding ntoskrnl, depending on the status of symbols.  It's been many years since I played with (DOS 3.x) debug, so this has been a considerable fumble.  Excerpts follow and any insights would be greatly appreciated, as I am not a developer:

ADDITIONAL_DEBUG_TEXT:
Use '!findthebuild' command to search for the target build information.
If the build information is available, run '!findthebuild -s ; .reload' to set symbol path and load symbols.

MODULE_NAME: nt

FAULTING_MODULE: fffff8000305d000 nt

DEBUG_FLR_IMAGE_TIMESTAMP:  4b88cfeb

BUGCHECK_STR:  0x7f_8

CUSTOMER_CRASH_COUNT:  1

DEFAULT_BUCKET_ID:  VISTA_DRIVER_FAULT

CURRENT_IRQL:  0

LAST_CONTROL_TRANSFER:  from fffff800030ccb69 to fffff800030cd600

STACK_TEXT:
fffff800`04d6fd28 fffff800`030ccb69 : 00000000`0000007f 00000000`00000008 00000000`80050033 00000000`000006f8 : nt+0x70600
fffff800`04d6fd30 00000000`0000007f : 00000000`00000008 00000000`80050033 00000000`000006f8 fffff800`03095e58 : nt+0x6fb69
fffff800`04d6fd38 00000000`00000008 : 00000000`80050033 00000000`000006f8 fffff800`03095e58 00000000`00000000 : 0x7f
fffff800`04d6fd40 00000000`80050033 : 00000000`000006f8 fffff800`03095e58 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : 0x8
fffff800`04d6fd48 00000000`000006f8 : fffff800`03095e58 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : 0x80050033
fffff800`04d6fd50 fffff800`03095e58 : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : 0x6f8
fffff800`04d6fd58 00000000`00000000 : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : nt+0x38e58

STACK_COMMAND:  kb

FOLLOWUP_IP: 
nt+70600
fffff800`030cd600 48894c2408      mov     qword ptr [rsp+8],rcx

SYMBOL_STACK_INDEX:  0

SYMBOL_NAME:  nt+70600

FOLLOWUP_NAME:  MachineOwner

IMAGE_NAME:  ntoskrnl.exe

BUCKET_ID:  WRONG_SYMBOLS

Followup: MachineOwner
......................................................................
0: kd> !lmi nt
Loaded Module Info: [nt] 
         Module: ntkrnlmp
   Base Address: fffff8000305d000
     Image Name: ntkrnlmp.exe
   Machine Type: 34404 (X64)
     Time Stamp: 4b88cfeb Sat Feb 27 00:55:23 2010
           Size: 5dc000
       CheckSum: 545094
Characteristics: 22  perf
Debug Data Dirs: Type  Size     VA  Pointer
             CODEVIEW    25, 19c65c,  19bc5c RSDS - GUID: {7E9A3CAB-6268-45DE-8E10-816E3080A3B7}
               Age: 2, Pdb: ntkrnlmp.pdb
                CLSID     4, 19c658,  19bc58 [Data not mapped]
     Image Type: FILE     - Image read successfully from debugger.
                 ntkrnlmp.exe
    Symbol Type: PDB      - Symbols loaded successfully from symbol server.
                 d:\debugsymbols\ntkrnlmp.pdb\7E9A3CAB626845DE8E10816E3080A3B72\ntkrnlmp.pdb
    Load Report: public symbols , not source indexed 
                 d:\debugsymbols\ntkrnlmp.pdb\7E9A3CAB626845DE8E10816E3080A3B72\ntkrnlmp.pdb
0: kd> !analyze -v

---

- *
- Bugcheck Analysis                                    *
- *

  ---

UNEXPECTED_KERNEL_MODE_TRAP (7f)
This means a trap occurred in kernel mode, and it's a trap of a kind
that the kernel isn't allowed to have/catch (bound trap) or that
is always instant death (double fault).  The first number in the
bugcheck params is the number of the trap (8 = double fault, etc)
Consult an Intel x86 family manual to learn more about what these
traps are. Here is a *portion* of those codes:
If kv shows a taskGate
        use .tss on the part before the colon, then kv.
Else if kv shows a trapframe
        use .trap on that value
Else
        .trap on the appropriate frame will show where the trap was taken
        (on x86, this will be the ebp that goes with the procedure KiTrap)
Endif
kb will then show the corrected stack.
Arguments:
Arg1: 0000000000000008, EXCEPTION_DOUBLE_FAULT
Arg2: 0000000080050033
Arg3: 00000000000006f8
Arg4: fffff80003095e58

### Debugging Details:

BUGCHECK_STR:  0x7f_8

CUSTOMER_CRASH_COUNT:  1

DEFAULT_BUCKET_ID:  VISTA_DRIVER_FAULT

PROCESS_NAME:  System

CURRENT_IRQL:  2

LAST_CONTROL_TRANSFER:  from fffff800030ccb69 to fffff800030cd600

STACK_TEXT:
fffff800`04d6fd28 fffff800`030ccb69 : 00000000`0000007f 00000000`00000008 00000000`80050033 00000000`000006f8 : nt!KeBugCheckEx
fffff800`04d6fd30 fffff800`030cb032 : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : nt!KiBugCheckDispatch+0x69
fffff800`04d6fe70 fffff800`03095e58 : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : nt!KiDoubleFaultAbort+0xb2
fffff880`089efc60 00000000`00000000 : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : nt!SeAccessCheckFromState+0x58

STACK_COMMAND:  kb

FOLLOWUP_IP: 
nt!KiDoubleFaultAbort+b2
fffff800`030cb032 90              nop

SYMBOL_STACK_INDEX:  2

SYMBOL_NAME:  nt!KiDoubleFaultAbort+b2

FOLLOWUP_NAME:  MachineOwner

MODULE_NAME: nt

IMAGE_NAME:  ntkrnlmp.exe

DEBUG_FLR_IMAGE_TIMESTAMP:  4b88cfeb

FAILURE_BUCKET_ID:  X64_0x7f_8_nt!KiDoubleFaultAbort+b2

BUCKET_ID:  X64_0x7f_8_nt!KiDoubleFaultAbort+b2

### Followup: MachineOwner

I tried running Rootkit Revealer but I don't think it works on x64 systems.  Similarly Blacklight seems to have aged off.  I'm running Sophos Anti-Rootkit now.  So far so good...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a known conflict in running both AVG and Zone Alarm.  If you Google "avg zonealarm" (without quotes) you will see quite a few links.  I uninstalled AVG and then reinstalled AVG but without the Link Scanner component and that solved my problem.

Comment: Superb!  I went the other direction and nuked Zone Alarm in favor of Comodo because I wanted to keep Link Scanner.  Leak Test and Shields Up gave the same perfect results and my system has been stable for several hours.  Now I'd better fix up my wife's system or she will be really annoyed.  :) Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 0):

BSODs are almost always either hardware or driver issues.

Given you removed Norton, maybe some aspect of some Norton driver was left, just enough that certain occasional kernel operations are failing.

You have two options: try and clean up manually, or re-pave. The latter is likely to be much easier and more reliable.

Comment: I suspected remnants and previously searched my registry for Norton.  Finding none, I continued searching for answers.  Thank goodness for this site and thank you for taking the time to reply.  I guess I'd better go buy some DVD's and create a backup in case I need to re-pave someday.